# Webscraping: book page images inside reader?

Tags: python, web-scraping

The image below shows source code, I came across while web scraping. The link to website is [URL](https://www.rekhta.org/ebooks/sab-rang-ebooks?lang=ur). It is basically online book reader which shows rendered images of books. What's so weird is I am unable to find any "img" or "src" tags or any url to these images. Any hint how to scrap this.

[image]

Comment: It is done by javascript. Go through the scripts and see which one of them is downloading the images.

Comment: The image is not in the div, it is in the canvas: `<canvas width="734" height="1080" class="canvas actualmage" style="
">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>`

Comment: The canvas is tainted.